# get object name dynamically with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have several json `objects` returned from a ajax call as:

```
...
main: [{
 0: { // i'm showing only one... have severals
    IMGNAM0: "856f070054d378fa5681332095257c3c94d5f858.jpg"
    IMGNAM1: "68dfda9de984e914b7027c4a3cda51fb375dd828.jpg"
    IMGNAM2: "da0a1a3f68af208baca5eae23900548b40adfbef.jpg"
    IMGNAM3: "c8b540f8bdfe054e3c888e800b380dd60a4ac371.jpg"
    IMGNAM4: "565eb06485c51123786a88b8d5537c6b45add950.jpg"
    IMGPAT0: "./static/uploaded_images/1/"
    IMGPAT1: "./static/uploaded_images/1/"
    IMGPAT2: "./static/uploaded_images/1/"
    IMGPAT3: "./static/uploaded_images/1/"
    IMGPAT4: "./static/uploaded_images/1/"
 }
}]
...
```

so, i need to get this obj names dynamically, i make a fast preview with something that i'm trying to do:

```
var mainlen = data.main.length-1; // get number of obj
for(var i = 0; i <= mainlen; i++){
   for(var j = 0; j <= 4; j++){ // examples to get all 4 obj names
        if(data.main[i].IMGNAM+j != null){
             // trying to get IMGNAM0 concatenate with j
             console.log(data.main[i].IMGNAM+j); 
             console.log(data.main[i].IMGPAT+j);
        }
   }
}
```

console shows me as `not a number (NaN)`, 
What is the best way to make this work ?

Comment: `for (var key in data.morrows[i]) { /* do something */ }`.

Comment: edit my question, with `data.main[i]`

Comment: Ah, didn't even notice the different name. Doesn't matter though, you use a `for...in` loop to iterate over the property names of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a point to acces to the data, with `.IMGNAM+j`, use `[IMGNAM+j]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code as below:

```
var mainlen = data.main.length-1; // get number of obj
for(var i = 0; i <= mainlen; i++){
   for(var j = 0; j <= 4; j++){ // examples to get all 4 obj names
        if(data.morrows[i].['IMGNAM'+j] != null){
             // trying to get IMGNAM0 concatenate with j
             console.log(data.main[i].['IMGNAM'+j]); 
             console.log(data.main[i].['IMGPAT'+j]);
        }
   }
}
```

this should solve your problem

Comment: `data.main[i].['IMGNAM'+j]` should be `data.main[i]['IMGNAM'+j]`.

Comment: change the if to `data.main` .

Answer (score 0):

You need something like:

```
 data.morrows[i]["IMGNAM" + j];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use square brackets to wrap your concatenated string:

```
if(data.main[i]['IMAGNAM'+j] != null){
```